# wrap more than one nodes with div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i wrap exactly half of the div's with another div using jquery or javascript

I have this

```
<div class="post">1</div>
<div class="post">2</div>
<div class="post">3</div>
<div class="post">4</div>
<div class="post">5</div>
<div class="post">6</div>
```

I want this

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="post">1</div>
  <div class="post">2</div>
  <div class="post">3</div>
</div>    
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="post">4</div>
  <div class="post">5</div>
  <div class="post">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
var posts = $('.post'),
    postCount = posts.length,
    postHalf = Math.round(postCount/2),
    wrapHTML = '<div class="wrap"></div>';

posts.slice(0, postHalf).wrapAll(wrapHTML); // .slice(0, 3)
posts.slice(postHalf, postCount).wrapAll(wrapHTML); // .slice(3, 6)
```

This selects all `.post`, gets the number of elements found then halves that value to get the splitting point. It then uses [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to select a specific range of elements and [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to wrap each selection in `<div class="wrap"></div>`.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/ekzrb/