# How to wrap more than one div around a div

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, grid-layout

I have a div (`Slideshow`) and I want to wrap around it small divs (`Items`). The `Slideshow` div will be static and the `Items` will be rendered automatically using a `Repeater Control`.

I made this image to better illustrate what I need to achieve.

[image]

I saw this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203809/wrap-more-than-one-nodes-with-div) and I thought I could use the same logic, let the `Repeater` items get rendered normally and then change the markup using JavaScript and use some sort of a CSS Grid layout to style the first 4 items for example on the left and the right and the rest will be beneath them but I'm not sure how to do it plus if there's a more simple solution I thought it could be cleaner than using the concept I saw in the question I referred.

**Update1**: Changed the picture to show the exact desired output

Comment: The linked question uses "wrap" in the sense of adding a parent container to an element.  But your question seems to use "wrap" in the sense of elements that surround but don't contain another element.  Could you clarify, perhaps by including the expected HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a Masonary layout. This plug in may be helpful, https://github.com/desandro/masonry

You could do this with bootstrap columns as well. For the first row, with the slideshow, you have 3 columns. The outer left and right columns will have 2 nested rows. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/. This is what Im most familiar with so I'll show you how I would implement a solution for the first row and how to implement a second row with 4 columns.

```
<div class="row">

    <!-- Outer Left Column -->
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                Item
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                Item
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        Slide Show
    </div>

    <!-- Outer Right Column -->
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                Item
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                Item
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Row With Four Items -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        Item
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        Item
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        Item
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        Item
    </div>
</div>
```

Checkout the angular material layout system as well. This will be harder to implement though because it requires Angular. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/layout/grid

Comment: This isn't really an answer; it is just suggestions on where to look.

Comment: These are good ways of implementing my output statically but my items are generated dynamically from the database so I need the items to find their way dynamically into the layout.

Comment: You can do that with javascript. Use `document.createElement` to generate the elements. You can also get an element and add a class name to it  `document.getElementById('foo').className += ' class_two'`

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution out and see if you can adopt it to your project: http://jsfiddle.net/1b0hoked/.

HTML:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div id = "slideshow"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*, :before, :after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
    counter-reset: item-counter;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    outline: 1px solid gray;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow {
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    line-height: 210px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -105px;
}

#slideshow:before {
    content: "Slide Show";
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: bold 16px/1 Sans-Serif;
    color: red;
}

.item {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:  96px;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
}

.item:before {
    counter-increment: item-counter;
    content: "item " counter(item-counter);
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: bold 12px/1 Sans-Serif;
    color: #aaa;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.item:nth-of-type(4n + 1) {
    clear: left;
}

.item:nth-of-type(3) {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -105px;
}

.item:nth-of-type(4) {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-left: -105px;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
    clear: left;
}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var numToAdd = 50;
    while(--numToAdd >= 0) {
        $("</p>").addClass("item").appendTo("#wrapper");    
    }
});
```